# How to pass $(this) in success callback of $.ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback, parameter-passing, this

I have seen a few different examples of accessing $(this) is the success callback of ajax but none give me the answer I want - they all access $(this) within the ajax function, I want to pass $(this) to a separate function.

So if there are 2 textboxes that need to be validated

```
$("#tb1").focusout(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: 'validURL',
        data: {various_parameters},
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(data){
            validInput(data, $(this));
        },
        error: error
    });
}

$("#tb2").focusout(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: 'validURL',
        data: {various_parameters},
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(data){
            validInput(data, $(this));
        },
        error: error
    });
}

function validInput(response, obj){
    console.log(response.d);
    console.log(obj.val());
};
```

When I run the code I get the correct value for response.d but an error : jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined for obj.val().

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks for any help.
See:Dos/Run

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`$(this)` is relative to the inner-most function, and in this case you'll need to assign `$(this)` to a variable before the ajax query, and use that variable in the success instead.

```
$("#tb1").focusout(function(){
    var elem = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: 'validURL',
        data: {various_parameters},
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(data){
            validInput(data, elem);
        },
        error: error
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @Hazonko - is the issue with $(this) being "relative" an issue only when using ajax or is it any time $(this) is passed?

Comment: if you have nested functions `this will refer to the inner most function

Answer (score 9):

Well that is because context of focusout element is lost in ajax call.

You can set `context` option in ajax to reference of DOM object for setting context in ajax to element context:

```
$("#tb2").focusout(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url: 'validURL',
    context : this,
    data: {various_parameters},
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType:'json',
    success: function(data){
        validInput(data, $(this));
    },
    error: error
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternative way you can achieve this is by referencing it in the first place.

```
$("#tb2").focusout(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: 'validURL',
        data: {various_parameters},
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(data){
            validInput(data, $this);
        },
        error: error
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'this' keyword within your success function, is a different 'this' that exists before your Ajax call, it's a different '**scope**'.

Make a new variable for the initial 'this' so you can use it within the success callback, like so:

```
$("#tb1").focusout(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: 'validURL',
        data: {various_parameters},
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(data){
            // Here we use the $this variable, initialised before the $.ajax call.
            validInput(data, $this);
        },
        error: error
    });
}
```