# JavaScript / jQuery: How to provide filtered Ajax data based on the selection made

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple buttons which represent different categories. When user clicks on either of them, I want to provide filtered data based on the selection. I dont want to make multiple Ajax requests but one request and an event listener which checks which button was clicked and provide filtered data based on the selection.

Below code does not work because I think if, else statements are nested in the Ajax request. How should I achieve my desired result without making multiple Ajax requests?

```
$( "#buttonA, #buttonB, #buttonC, #buttonD" ).click(function() {

    $.ajax({
      url: "{% url 'data_for_buttons' %}",
      method: 'GET',
      data : {
      my_category: 1,
             },
      success: function(dataset){

          if (this.id == 'buttonA') {
              alert('Button A is clicked'); // Provide A data to user
           }
          else if (this.id == 'buttonB') {
             alert('Button B is clicked'); // Provide B data to user
          }
          else if (this.id == 'buttonC') {
             alert('Button C is clicked'); // Provide C data to user
          } 
          else (this.id == 'buttonD') {
             alert('Button D is clicked'); // Provide D data to user
          }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`context`, your response function needs to have the proper context. So set it for the ajax request via:

```
context: $(this),
success: function(dataset){
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
}
```

Comment: That's fully right, also you can `var elem = $(this);` set this before the $.ajax and use it as function args: `success: function(data){
            successCallback(data, elem);
        }` This approach was answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37410567/how-to-pass-this-in-success-callback-of-ajax

Comment: Don't you want the `my_category: 1 ` part to reflect which button was pressed? If so, this solution will not fix it.

Answer (score 0):

To know which button has been clicked, you can try this:

```
$( "#buttonA, #buttonB, #buttonC, #buttonD" ).on('click', function(eventObj) {
$.ajax({
      url: "{% url 'data_for_buttons' %}",
      method: 'GET',
      data : {
      my_category: 1,
             },
      success: function(dataset){

          if (eventObj.currentTarget.id == 'buttonA') {
              alert('Button A is clicked'); // Provide A data to user
           }
          etc ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not misunderstanding your question something like this should work:

```
$( "#buttonA, #buttonB, #buttonC, #buttonD" ).click(function() {
   const BUTTON_ID_TO_CATEGORY_MAP = {
      buttonA: 1,
      buttonB: 2,
      buttonC: 3,
      buttonD: 4
    };
    let category = BUTTON_ID_TO_CATEGORY_MAP[this.id];

    $.ajax({
      url: "{% url 'data_for_buttons' %}",
      method: 'GET',
      data : {
             my_category: category,
      },
      success: function(dataset){
                    // do stuff 
      }});
});
```

So the only difference here is that we're checking which button was pressed **before** we do the AJAX call, so that the AJAX call can be made for the category corresponding to the clicked button.

That means that when we get the result, it's already filtered (if I understand your AJAX call correctly), so we don't have to worry about the buttons any more.